# Element insert before: fetch elements that has been added using insertAfter

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

In my application we are using tree structure and on each click of + ( expand) ajax call is triggered which renders its respective child elements using Element.insert ( prototype.js)
Now i need to have this element using .children() . but i dont receive it

To insert child elements on + we use below

```
var Insertion = {
  Before: function(element, content) {
    return Element.insert(element, {before:content});
  },

  Top: function(element, content) {
    return Element.insert(element, {top:content});
  },
    Bottom: function(element, content) {
       
            
        return Element.insert(element, {bottom:content});
      }
}
```

Now when i try to find child of parent node, i did not receive this newly added node content

for example below is my ul li

```
    <ul class="list">
   <li class="node minus" id="node_7361">
      <a href="#" class="node activeNode" id="parentLabel">XXX</a>
      <span class="informal" style="display: none;">
      </span>
      <ul class="qualificationList">
         <li></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now when i try to find children using $('.list > li').children() i get only first two child( a and span) and not third one(ul), as this  added using Element.insert
Note : `<li> has three child above`

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: IN project we are using prototype js and some part is using Jquery also, so when i want to search something from tree , i need to get this element as children , as only when u click on + content is loaded, and not on load

Comment: But there's nothing that uses jQuery in the question, so the tag was inappropriate. I replaced it with the prototypejs tag -- I assume that's where `Element.insert()` comes from (I'm not familiar with that library).

Comment: It would be best if you posted a [mre] to show how you're calling this code and then trying to access the children. I don't think `Before` will create children of the element, it creates a sibling.

Comment: Yes have added details

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you are using `$('.list > li').children()` to get all the children, which is called through jQuery. Have you tried using the PrototypeJS method and see what results you get? I've had issues in the past where PrototypeJS directly updates the DOM, but method calls immediately after using jQuery don't see the DOM updates because of some issue (I guessed DOM/CSS caching but I could be wrong).

So try getting the list of child elements with `$$('.list > li').first().childElements()` ?

Comment: Nopes it didnt worked